# show that the mapping $f: (\mathbb{R},\ell_1) → (\mathbb{R},\ell_2)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

show that the mapping $f: (\mathbb{R},\ell_1) → (\mathbb{R},\ell_2)$ is continuous.

$f(x) = 0, x=-3$ and $\sqrt 3, x\neq-3$

$ł_1=\{U\subset \mathbb{R}: U=\emptyset \lor-3\in U   \}$
$ł_2=\{U\subset \mathbb{R}: U=\mathbb{R} \lor\sqrt 3\notin U   \}$

So first I took

$U=\mathbb{R}$

And $f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb{R} \in ł_1$

Then I took U where $\sqrt 3 \notin U$

And $f^{-1}(U) = \{-3\} \in ł_1$

So this mapping is continuous correct?

And I have another question if yes,so why $f^{-1}(U) = \{-3\}$ where U is the set where $\sqrt 3 \notin U$. I draw a picture of this function but I don't see it.

Comment: Does ${\rm l}_1$ does for the $\ell_1$ space and the other ${\rm l}_2$ for the $\ell_2$ space?

Comment: @Tolaso Yes exactly

Comment: Some formatting note. You may use `\mathbb{R}` in order to refer to the set of real numbers and (optional) `\ell` or `l` for the space. I would not suggest that symbol. Regards.

Comment: How is $f$ defined exactly? $f(x) = ?$ for $x = ?$. It's quite unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to parse this question, but I think what you're asking is the following:

We have two topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ on the set $\mathbb{R}$. $\tau_1$ is the included-point topology with respect to $-3$, while $\tau_2$ is the excluded-point topology with respect to $\sqrt{3}$. (using $\ell$ for these is too non-standard for me).

We then consider a function $f: (\mathbb{R}, \tau_1) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\tau_2)$, defined by $f(-3) = 0$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{3}$ otherwise. (I think, but the question is unclear!).

Now, $f^{-1}[U ] =\mathbb{R}$ for $U = \mathbb{R}$ (you don't really have to check this for continuity, it holds for any function).

So if $U$ is another open set of $\tau_2$ we only know that $\sqrt{3} \notin U$.

$f^{-1}[U ]= \{x: f(x) \in U \}$ by definition, so $f^{-1}[U] = \{-3\}$ or $f^{-1}[U] = \emptyset$, depending on whether $0 \in U$ or not.

In either case, $f^{-1}[U]$ is open, so indeed $f$ is continuous.